# How to add a language dropdown switcher to top panel?

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

I try to create a multilingual (3 languages, incl. English) website, and I’d like to create a language dropdown switcher (ideally in the top panel/menu). I tried to accomplish this using Flags, and Language Dropdown Switcher, but couldn’t display it though. It presume, I just don’t know how to add it in a block; although I could find the Language Dropdown Switcher in the block and add it there, but it did not show up. I could set the Flags up in the Configuration, but I did not find it in the blocks.

How do I install/enable/place a language dropdown switcher (preferably Flags, but this is not a condition)? It would be awesome (again: this is not necessary) if this switcher would be in the top panel and that it would contain country flags only (not the language as text).

Drupal 8.5.6 with `configuration translation`, `content translation`, `interface translation` and `language` enabled and the particular languages are already added in the configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe Flags does not integrate with `Language switcher dropdown` (contrib module) it only integrates with the core `language switcher block`

Here is some alternatives

## 1. [Language Switcher Dropdown](https://www.drupal.org/project/lang_dropdown) + [languageicons](https://www.drupal.org/project/languageicons)

- Install both modules
- Go to `config > regional and language > language icons` and choose

  > **Icon placement**
  >     Before link
  >     After link
  >     Replace link
- Go to `Structure > block layout` add `Language dropdown switcher` block to your desired region

## 2. [Bootstrap Languages](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap_languages)

Compatible with bootstrap based themes only

- Install module
- Go to `Structure > block layout` add `Bootstrap Language switcher` block to your desired region

## 3. [dropdown_language](https://www.drupal.org/project/dropdown_language)

With this module icons have to be setup manually using css

Comment: To be noted  that the use of flag icons for languages has been criticized as poor design. The symbolism of a national flag introduces politicization, and often ambiguity.
See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_icons_for_languages